# Clojure Secretary - Dispatch on URL Change

Tags: clojure, url-routing, secretary

Can Secretary dispatch routes based on a submitted browser url, the way many javascript routing frameworks work? I can't seem to find any examples of wiring this up.

For example, when you enter http://myapp.com/#/my/route in the browser's url, I'd like that to dispatch as though I had programatically entered (secretary/dispatch! "/my/route") in the repl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can, but not by itself. The most common way of doing this is with Google Closure, as in the README.md example:

```
(let [h (History.)]
  (goog.events/listen h EventType/NAVIGATE #(secretary/dispatch! (.-token %)))
  (doto h (.setEnabled true)))
```

When you call `setEnabled` in the example above, the `NAVIGATE` event will automatically fire for the current location which will cause `dispatch!` to be invoked.